# The simplest way to emulate TCP-IP protocol violation / anomaly attacks

Tags: web-application, attacks, ip, tcp, anomaly-detection

Reading up upon security on web applications I did not found that much info on TCP-IP and in particular HTTP/UDP protocol violation / anomaly attacks. My question:

What is the general mechanism of such attack? As I understand an invalid HTTP/UDP request is sent to the server that it then tries to read an execute - can you offer a deeper explanation?

Comment: The arenin general referred to as AET 'advanced evasion techniques', stonesoft ran an automated study and found many thousands. Sorry i cannot respond in detail, this is top technical and sensitive. I think scapy might be what you are looking for as a tool for lab testing.

Comment: Your questions 2 and 3 are off topic here, and you answered 4 yourself. If you have separate questions, please ask them separately.